# Datatables data form JSON, with $.GetJSON

Tags: jquery, json, symfony, datatables, getjson

Im working in symfony and trying to send data with JSON to datatables.

My symfony controller is returning array, tried dumping the data and its all ok on this part.

```
 return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($ret);
```

On the other part i have this table

```
<table id="user-list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is my javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var $jquery_1_11_3 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        console.log('jquery ver.:', $().jquery);
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    ajaxPaths = {
                        getAllWordpressJobs: "{{ path('json_getAllWordpressJobs') }}",
                    },
                    getItems = function () {
                        return $.Deferred(function () {
                            var that = this;
                            $.getJSON(ajaxPaths.getAllWordpressJobs, function (data) {
                                that.resolve(data);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    showItemsTable = function () {
                        return $.Deferred(function () {
                            var that = this;
                            getItems().done(function (itemsData) {
                                console.log(itemsData);
                                try {
                                    itemsTable = $('#user-list').DataTable({

                                        data: itemsData,
                                        columns: [
                                            {"data": "id"},
                                            {"data": "title"},
                                            {"data": "content"},
                                            {"data": "author"},
                                            {"data": "date"},
                                            {"data": "status"}
                                        ]
                                    });
                                    console.log(itemsTable);

                                    that.resolve();
                                }catch (e) {
                                    console.log(e.message);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
         showItemsTable();
        });
    </script>
```

Problem is that i have no data in datatable, there are no logs in console also,

[image]

What is the right way to put data from Json response into datatable using getJSON